# Where is this story of death of a Hindu avatar found?

Tags: scripture, avatars, identification-request

As a child I heard this story about a Hindu avatar which has stayed with me as I find it very interesting.

It's regarding death of one of the Vishnu's avatar (or that of an another Hindu god). The avatar was sent to do a particular thing on earth but after doing that he becomes too *indulgent* in the family life of the avatar. That is he forgets he is a God and continues to live life like an ordinary man with love for his wife and family. On seeing this, the gods then send somebody to *kill* the avatar so to release him from worldly life and bring him back to heavens.

Can somebody please provide more details about this story as in who this avatar was and other information?

Comment: This story is similar to the Shiva Purana story of Lord Vishnu rescuing the apsaras from Patala but then marrying them and forgetting about the world- resulting in Rishabha avatara of Lord Shiva.

Comment: It's Varaha avatar. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varaha).
Swamy Vivekananda also quoted this in one of his lectures to give an example of the strength of Maya.

Comment: Possible duplicate or at least linked to this - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/what-scriptures-describe-krishna-teaching-narada-about-maya

Comment: An Avatara does not have a physical body of panchabhutas.So the word 'death' is not used for ANY avatar.